# json multidimensional array $.each

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array, getjson

I can get the 'name' values but not the 'Orders' seems the Orders are returned as object not Array?

json.json

```
[{ "ID":"23",
"LastName":"Moe",
"FirstName":"Ronnie",
"Orders":[{"OrderNumber":"11","ItemNumber":"22"},
             {"OrderNumber":"33","ItemNumber":"44"}]}]
```

myHTML.html

```
$.getJSON('json.json',  
    {},
    function (data) {  
     $.each( data, function ( i, val ) {
        var lastname=this.LastName; 
        var firstname=this.FirstName;
        var orders=this.Orders;

        $.each(data.Orders, function(property, value) {
        alert(property + "=" + value);

        //Insert the data to HTML page
        $(".title").append('<li>'+lastname+', '+firstname+'  >'+'</li>');
        $(".title").append('<li>'+orders+'</li>');

        });

    });
    }) 
 });
```

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/jcr79/3/ as mentioned below - you are iterating over data twice.

Comment: still returns [object] and not value - I updates jsfiddle.net to show results with alert..?

Comment: Thats because alert will toString it, console.log will log the whole object. If you switched it to `alert(value.OrderNumber)` or something similar you will see values.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works! I was confused with the object - how do I give you credit for this answer?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer and you can accept it :) glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/jcr79/3 as mentioned below - you are iterating over data twice. You need to point to the correct datasource.

As for the alert, you need to alert the properties for the object, not the whole object. E.g. `alert(value.OrderNumber)`

Alert will simply print out the string representation of the object ("[object object]").

Console.log will log the entire object.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: one last question: on jsfiddle the console.log didn't show any output? I'm new to this, where would I see the run results?

Comment: If you have chrome and hit f12 it will bring up the developer tools. From there you can open the console. Ctrl + shift + J is the shortcut to directly open the console (the icon starts with this symbol > followed by 3 horizontal lines). In the fiddle provided you should see 2 Objects that are expandable in the console. Expanding them should show you the attributes an object has and the values they contain.

Comment: Also, this is the definitive guide to the developer tools in Chrome https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console. IE and firefox both have these, I am just familiar with Chrome as it's my browser of choice.

Answer (score 2):

Should be `this.Orders` or `val.Orders`, not `data.Orders`